# how to store register value as dict in ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to convert a string

From `"{ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0},{ip: 10.213.151.799, mask: 255.255.252.0}"`

to `[{ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0}, {ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0}]`.

Playbook code

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - vari: "[{ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0},{ip: 10.213.151.799, mask: 255.255.252.0}]"
    - foo: []
  tasks:
    - set_fact: testing={{vari[1:-1] | regex_findall('\{(.*?)\}')}}
#    - set_fact: testing={{vari[1:-1]}}
    - debug: var=testing
    - name: run my script!
      command: python ../test.py  "{{item}}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      register: hash
      with_items: "{{testing}}"
    - debug: var=hash
    - set_fact: foo={{foo + item.stdout_lines}}
      with_items: "{{hash.results}}"
    - debug: var=foo
```

pyhon script which converts a string to dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
ip_str = str(sys.argv[1])
print dict(s.split(': ') for s in (ip_str.split(', ')))
```

Current **foo** variable value coming like this.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": [
        "{'ip': '10.213.151.76', 'mask': '255.255.252.0'}",
        "{'ip': '10.213.151.799', 'mask': '255.255.252.0'}"
    ]
}
```

Basically, i want this value in the list of hash format: [{ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0}, {ip: 10.213.151.76, mask: 255.255.252.0}].

Python script return value as a dictionary but register store it as a string. ansible not able to convert it as a dictonary.

Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try with `print json.dumps(dict(s.split(': ') for s in (ip_str.split(', '))))` and `foo + (item.stdout | from_json)`. But it seems you're on the wrong path and should redesign your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if it's this complex, I think you should consider redesigning. However...

You can write a variables file in one play, and read it in the next.

```
- name: dynamic vars file write test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: write it
      shell: ' echo "foo: bar">tst.yml '

- name: dynamic vars file read test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
   - tst.yml
  tasks:
   - name: read it
     debug:
       msg: "{{foo}}"
```

Which outputs:

```
PLAY [dynamic vars file write test]   
********************************************

TASK [write it]
********************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [dynamic vars file read test]     
********************************************

TASK [read it]
********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "bar"
}
```

This makes it a heck of a lot easier to format and parse, at least for me.